# How do I know if AWS S3 client 1.11.214 is slow and to which version to upgrade it?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using aws client 1.11.214 in my microservice and I see that the copyobject function `com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3#copyObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` is taking a lot of percentage of cpu flame graph as shown by the async profiler. How can I know if there is a problem with the client I am using (maybe I should upgrade it) or is there something wrong I am doing in my code?
If the client is old and needs to be upgraded, how do I know to which version should I upgrade? is it always best to upgrade to the newest one?

This was an existing service in the company I work in and it did not work very well, the lag time of the kafka messages was 4 minutes in the best times and when there was a big load it could get to 20 minutes or more. So I started enhancing the service and when I used the async profiler to create the flame graph I saw that a lot of the CPU is being spent on Amazon s3 copyObject.

Comment: Yes it's a good idea to use the latest - the latest for V1 is `1.12.552` as per Maven Central - https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3

Comment: Hey, I will use it but do you know if there was any time complexity improvements between the sdk I am using and this one?

Comment: I don’t know for sure - but please upgrade it, check again, share some minimal code if still having issues.

Comment: okay will do. How can I make sure that there are no API changes? (at least for two functions: 

putObject(String bucketName, String key, String content)

copyObject(String sourceBucketName, String sourceKey,
            String destinationBucketName, String destinationKey)

Comment: Update and try - but those are bog standard methods.